# System.EntryPointNotFoundException MVC5

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

My website runs fine from visual studio but as soon as I deploy it to IIS I get the following error.

```
Entry point was not found. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.InnerSetResolver(IDependencyResolver resolver) +289
   Rabobank.Risk.LicwidWorkflow.UI.UnityConfig.RegisterComponents() +125
   Rabobank.Risk.LicwidWorkflow.UI.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +30

[HttpException (0x80004005): Entry point was not found.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12602733
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Entry point was not found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12619780
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12459397
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Check your web.config file and check the assembly references and their version with referenced version.

Comment: Make sure that you have correct version of unity that supports the version of MVC you are using - e.g make sure you have the `Unity.MVC5` package from Nuget if you are using MVC5.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when using dependency injection.
If you have multiple projects referencing each other make sure they target the same framework or compatible frameworks. Also check all the package.config files and make sure that the targetFramework for each xml line matches your projects target framework.